# Is escaping enough protection against sql injection in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-injection

I read that escaping input is not enough protection against sql injection.

Then, I saw that codeigniter does not use prepared statements.

It uses `escape` and `bind` (which is still just escape) when executing queries.

Would this be enough protection?

If not, should I avoid Query Class and use prepared PDO queries manually?

Comment: explanation on why this questions / these answers are downvoted, are always welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right in your assumption to avoid the builtin query class, and to use PDO with prepared queries.

Don't use things that are not prepared, unless you're making a plugin, then for the sake of future users you might consider using the builtins to allow easier debugging for them, but still then, consider using a more secure prepared statement supported way.

You really don't want to be the plugin author responsible for a weakness in a site.

Comment: @DonJoe It does that indeed. The same with wordpress, it also uses a convoluted way to escape stuff. You can hardly see the code through the patches to fix vulnerabilities. I'd rather suggest you'd use a framework like octobercms, laravel, symfony, doctrine over CI.  Because they use prepared statements, support many database engines, and force you to upgrade to more secure php versions if you wish to update. The frameworks i listed are all family, with the youngest first and oldest most simple last.

Comment: Since CI is faster and easier to get started with than Laravel, do you  think is ok if I choose CI and use PDO for database?

Comment: @DonJoe I'd suggest you take a look at octobercms, its really easy to get into, has a forumand a chat where you can ask question and pretty good documentation. Its built on laravel so when you're up for a heartier meal you can start using laravel tricks and such. It also has a graphical model builder and form builder that will help you set up your plugins and such. Invest now, end up secure. Use CI and you'll always have that nagging doubt in the back of your head.

Answer (score 1):

From everything I've seen, PDO and prepared queries are the thing to pursue now. Seeing alot of PHP posts on here the majority of the comments are telling people to switch to more secure ways of accessing and inserting data into your database in the way of PDO. It is extremely well documented and once you grasp the fundamentals of it, it is very easy to see how it can be used further. TL:DR Escape = bad. PDO = Good

PDO documentation is also here that gives you a huge knowledge base of 'how to's ' which are very easy to follow and well written [PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: yes, but why would such a popular framework use just escaping and not prepared statements?

Comment: @DonJoe If you have the case of wordpress its their dubugging tools, backwards compatiability and a big dose of, we know it better than the rest. I theorise that CI elitists hhave a same mindset

Comment: Totally agree with @Tschallacka also 'old habits die hard' definitely come into play with a lot of programmers and they always use the excuse 'I know it so well though'